# MS Word Find and Replace text within all docs in a folder using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have come across the code below that searches through an open word document and performs a find and replace within all areas (StoryRanges) of the document.
It works fine, however i would like to ask how i could modify this code to look at all documents in a chosen folder and perform the find and replace for all docs within that folder?, rather than just the active document which is open?

My plan is to assign the macro to a button in Excel so that the user can click that, navigate to the folder and action the find and replace across lots of documents at once.

Am I able to amend the 'IN ActiveDocument.StoryRanges' section to look at a folder instead? I'm not sure what i can amend it to.  btw... i am new to vba and trying to research & learn as i go... I very much appreciate your time, patience and any help you can give while i'm trying to find my feet with it - Alex.

Dim myStoryRange As Range

```
    For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "Text to find to replace goes here"
        .Replacement.Text = "And the replacement text goes here"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Do While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
        Set myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
        With myStoryRange.Find
            .Text = "Text to find to replace goes here"
            .Replacement.Text = "And the replacement text goes here"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Loop
Next myStoryRange
```

Comment: By using `DIR` Do a search on SO or Google. You will find plenty of examples.

Comment: Lemme know if you are still stuck and we will take it from there :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been researching DIR and also came across FileSystemObjects.  I'm still thinking and trying to work out how /& which method i should incorporate. Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it. Still if you do then lemme know...

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
' This code uses Late Binding to connect to word and hence you '
' you don't need to add any references to it                   '
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'

Option Explicit

'~~> Defining Word Constants
Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1
Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2

Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, rngStory as Object
    Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName As String, sFileName As String

    '~~> Change this to the folder which has the files
    sFolder = "C:\Temp\"
    '~~> This is the extention you want to go in for
    strFilePattern = "*.docx"

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Loop through the folder to get the word files
    strFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

        '~~> Open the word doc
        Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)

        '~~> Do Find and Replace
        For Each rngStory In oWordDoc.StoryRanges
            With rngStory.Find
                .Text = "Text to find to replace goes here"
                .Replacement.Text = "And the replacement text goes here"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next

        '~~> Close the file after saving
        oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

        '~~> Find next file
        strFileName = Dir$()
    Loop

    '~~> Quit and clean up
    oWordApp.Quit

    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much! , very helpfull. i've just given this a try and it does go through the files and make replacements, however it doesnt replace all sections of the documents like the initial coding i posted. I need to find and replace text in headers and footers aswell as the main body of the document.  'MyStoryRange' can do it, but i just cant see how to get it to look at a whole folder of docs rather then just the active document.

Comment: Sadly it won't find words in tables and other sections of the document.